# Why do Karaite Jews wear a kippah in synagogues?

Tags: non-rabbinic-judaism

As far as I know, the only commandments followed by Karaites are those that are in  explicitly stated in the Torah. Why wear a yarmulke if this isn't commanded in the Torah? Here is a link about Karaite [Synagogue Etiquette](https://www.karaites.org/synagogue-etiquette.html)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! From what I know, the belief that Karaites only follow what is stated explicitly in the Torah is a myth. They have their own traditions about things.

Comment: Karaites have their own oral law, and besides, kippa is a custom, not law.

Answer (score 1):

Tradition.

Karaites despite their rejection of  Rabbinic Judaism still have their  own traditions on how certain laws  are kept, they have their  own sages, and their own culture etc. Their religion is not exclusively limited to a literal understanding of Torah with no other instructions.

They wear a kippah to synagogue only because it was  traditionally Jewish elements of worship. Before kippahs, they wore a fez. Before a fez, it was a turban. But the bottom line was that head coverings were worn during prayer in their synagogues so they still are today.

Comment: It's my understanding of Karaite Jews that the issue is not with the tradition. Everyone has a tradition. The issue is calling the rabbinic tradition an "Oral Torah" and elevating their requirements to mitzvot from Hashem. Huge difference. So if they cover their head for some reason, it's a personal preference or community tradition or simple respect for the customs of someone else's synagogue. I'm not a Jew. If I visit a synagogue, I wear one out of respect. Not because I'm commanded.